# Android read text file so slow

Tags: java, android

In my Android application I use FileInputStream to read a text file, which is less than 100 kb in size, and showing its content in the application. The main problem is that although the file is not so big it takes around 3-4 seconds for my device to open the file.

Considering the fact the my device has 1gb ram and a four-core CPU I want to know what's wrong with the way I read the text file and is there any better way to make the process faster?

```
String aBuffer = "";
    try {
        File myFile = new File(input);
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                fIn));
        String aDataRow = "";

        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
        }
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), aBuffer,
        // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        myReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    return aBuffer;
```

Comment: You should change your strategy. Don't load all the text at once. Do it progressively. At the end that's a lot of text!

Comment: Is there any way to load part of a text file?

Comment: Also, don't use String concatenation: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/strings.html

Comment: you know that Strings in java are immutable? you know how it affect string's concating?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your String concat is a very slow operation. You should use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) for this task:

```
String aDataRow = "";
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
    buffer.append(aDataRow);
    buffer.append("\n");
}
aDataRow = buffer.toString();
```

You can even speed up the reading, if you don't read your file line by line (because this is probably a very small buffer size). You can set a custom buffer size like this:

```
File myFile = new File(input);
FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
//needed to shrink the copied array in the last iteration of the length of the content
int byteLength;
//find a good buffer size here.
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 128];
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while((byteLength = fIn.read(buffer)) != -1){
    byte[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, byteLength);
    out.write(copy, 0, copy.length);
}
String output = out.toString();
```

Comment: thanks Simulant. it got a little better. is there is way to make it faster?

Comment: thanks a lot. it got really better. but one more question. for a file mostly around 100kb to 150kb what is the best size for buffer you mentioned?

Comment: Because your file is very small you buffer could be the size of your file i.e. 1024 * 150 byte. For the "perfect" size you have to test some different values on the device you are using and log the time needed.

Comment: Perfect! (also note that in the case where you are displaying content on the screen that is usually the largest time delay)

Answer (score 3):

- Find out the file size.
- Allocate a single buffer that is that size.
- Read the whole file at once into the buffer (ie. don't read it line by line, which is going to be slow)

Answer (score 0):

You should use threading for file read and write operations  because it slows down the main thread which slows down you reading speed as well as performance too.